# How to apply contain on last record and delete if found in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, filestream

I have a list of strings like

```
AAPL,28/03/2012,88.34,88.778,87.187,88.231,163682382
AAPL,29/03/2012,87.54,88.08,86.747,87.123,151551216
FB,30/03/2012,86.967,87.223,85.42,85.65,182255227
```

Now I want to delete only last record if it does not contains AAPL(symbol name) using LINQ.

Below I have write my code which contains multiple line but I want to make it single line code,

```
fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).AsParallel().Skip(1).ToList();
var lastLine = fileLines.Last();
if (!lastLine.Contains(item.sym))
{
    fileLines.RemoveAt(fileLines.Count - 1);
}
```

So How can I make all it in single line linq query ?

Comment: Why would you want to do it in LINQ? It's Language INtegrated Query... and you don't query, you manipulate. If it's simple and it works, don't make it more complicated just because Linq looks fancy.

Comment: `.AsParallel().Skip(1).ToList()` I'm not sure why you'd want to skip one *in parallel*. Do you really need the power of multiple CPUs to skip one single line?

Comment: @nvoigt I see your point; nonetheless, this could be thought of as a query as well. One say: "I want all items from that source; except the last item if it meets a particular condition". There seems to be no manipulation in that quote. Manipulation in OP's code happens only in `RemoveAt` from `fileLines` `List<string>` - a manipulation that could be avoided in the first place if we made a proper "query".

Comment: @nvoigt, Actually process is working with 10,000 text files and also I need to handle live websocket's data into all those files at a live stock market time. So for make process very speedy I need to use linq or plinq in implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ternary operator to decide on the tail to concatenate as follows.

```
fileLines
    = fileLines.Take(fileLines.Count())
               .Concat(fileLines.Last().Contains(item.sym) ? Enumerable.Empty
                                                           : new string[]{ item.sym });
```

You could formulate it even more contracted as follows.

```
fileLines
    = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Take(fileLines.Count())
                    .Concat(fileLines.Last().Contains(item.sym) ? Enumerable.Empty
                                                                : new string[]{ item.sym });
                    .ToList();
```

That being said, such an endeavour is questionable. The accumulation of lazily evaluated Linq extension methods is difficult to debug.

Comment: Methods like `Count()` and `Last()` could have grave impact on performance when used with `IEnumerable` objects that doesn't implement `IList<T>` [(see)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) - like `System.IO.ReadLinesIterator` that is returned by `ReadAllLines` and doesn't implement `IList<string>` - especially in that case where we also have IO-bound operations with every item as well.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need to simplify the filtering operation, and, from what I see in your case, you're missing only one piece of information (i.e whether or not current item is the last one in an enumerated collection) that will help you define your predicate. What I'm about to write now might not seem "a simple single line"; however, it's gonna be a reusable extension that will provide this piece of information (and more) without performing extra and unnecessary loops or iterations.

The final product of that will be:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName).RichWhere((item, originalIndex, countedIndex, hasMoreItems) => hasMoreItems || item.StartsWith("AAPL"));
```

The LINQ-like extension that I wrote inspired by Microsoft's [Enumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) at [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/):

```
public delegate bool RichPredicate<T>(T item, int originalIndex, int countedIndex, bool hasMoreItems);
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// This was contributed by Aly El-Haddad as an answer to this Stackoverflow.com question:
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/q/54829095/3602352
    /// </remarks>
    public static IEnumerable<T> RichWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, RichPredicate<T> predicate)
    {
        return new RichWhereIterator<T>(source, predicate);
    }
    private class RichWhereIterator<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly int threadId;
        private readonly IEnumerable<T> source;
        private readonly RichPredicate<T> predicate;
        private IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
        private int state;
        private int countedIndex = -1;
        private int originalIndex = -1;
        private bool hasMoreItems;

        public RichWhereIterator(IEnumerable<T> source, RichPredicate<T> predicate)
        {
            threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            this.source = source ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            this.predicate = predicate ?? ((item, originalIndex, countedIndex, hasMoreItems) => true);
        }
        public T Current { get; private set; }

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (enumerator is IDisposable disposable)
                disposable.Dispose();
            enumerator = null;
            originalIndex = -1;
            countedIndex = -1;
            hasMoreItems = false;
            Current = default(T);
            state = -1;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case 1:
                    enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
                    if (!(hasMoreItems = enumerator.MoveNext()))
                    {
                        Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                    ++originalIndex;
                    state = 2;
                    goto case 2;
                case 2:
                    if (!hasMoreItems) //last predicate returned true and that was the last item
                    {
                        Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                    T current = enumerator.Current;
                    hasMoreItems = enumerator.MoveNext();
                    ++originalIndex;
                    if (predicate(current, originalIndex - 1, countedIndex + 1, hasMoreItems))
                    {
                        ++countedIndex;
                        Current = current;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (hasMoreItems)
                    { goto case 2; }

                    //predicate returned false and there're no more items
                    Dispose();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Current = default(T);
            hasMoreItems = false;
            originalIndex = -1;
            countedIndex = -1;
            state = 1;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (threadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId && state == 0)
            {
                state = 1;
                return this;
            }
            return new RichWhereIterator<T>(source, predicate) { state = 1 };
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

`RichPredicate<T>`, which could be thought of as `Func<T, int, int, bool, bool>` provide this information about each item:

- **item**: the item to evaluate.
- **originalIndex**: the index of that item in its original `IEnumerable<T>` source (the one which was directly passed to `RichWhere`).
- **countedIndex**: the index of that item *IF* the predicate would evaluate to true.
- **hasMoreItems**: tells whether or not this would be the last item from the original `IEnumerable<T>` source.